# Updating/Inserting is not supported by data source

Tags: sql, database, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I've been making my first ASP.NET Visual Studio website and I have just started working with databases, I've made a table and a backoffice page for me to control the content of my table.

This page follows the following rules:

-> I've added the SQLDataSource and configured.

-> I've added a gridview to see my content and configured it to my SQLDataSource, here I've added the Edit/Delete options.

-> I've added a DetailsView configured to my SWLDataSource, here I've added New option (to create new entries in my table)

My database has the id column set as primary key (data type=int; allow nulls=not checked)

Every time I try to update my data base through this backoffice page I get the following error:

> Updating is not supported by data
>   source 'SqlDataSource1' unless
>   UpdateCommand is specified.
>   Description: An unhandled exception
>   occurred during the execution of the
>   current web request. Please review the
>   stack trace for more information about
>   the error and where it originated in
>   the code.
>
> Exception Details:
>   System.NotSupportedException: Updating
>   is not supported by data source
>   'SqlDataSource1' unless UpdateCommand
>   is specified.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated
>   during the execution of the current
>   web request. Information regarding the
>   origin and location of the exception
>   can be identified using the exception
>   stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [NotSupportedException: Updating is
>   not supported by data source
>   'SqlDataSource1' unless UpdateCommand
>   is specified.]
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceView.ExecuteUpdate(IDictionary
>   keys, IDictionary values, IDictionary
>   oldValues) +1644420
>   System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Update(IDictionary
>   keys, IDictionary values, IDictionary
>   oldValues,
>   DataSourceViewOperationCallback
>   callback) +92
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.HandleUpdate(GridViewRow
>   row, Int32 rowIndex, Boolean
>   causesValidation) +907
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.HandleEvent(EventArgs
>   e, Boolean causesValidation, String
>   validationGroup) +704
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.OnBubbleEvent(Object
>   source, EventArgs e) +95
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object
>   source, EventArgs args) +37
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRow.OnBubbleEvent(Object
>   source, EventArgs e) +123
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object
>   source, EventArgs args) +37
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.OnCommand(CommandEventArgs
>   e) +118
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument) +135
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument) +10
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler
>   sourceControl, String eventArgument)
>   +13    System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection
>   postData) +175
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean
>   includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1565

I could really use some help here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The errormessage says it all : 'Updating is not supported by data source 'SqlDataSource1' unless UpdateCommand is specified.'. You have to assign sql code or the name of a stored procedure to the property [UpdateCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.updatecommand.aspx) so that the SqlDataSource knows how to handle your update.

Comment: No problem. After all, we are here to help. Follow the link I placed in my post (under the word 'UpdateCommand') : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.updatecommand.aspx . Scroll to 'examples'. You can place the sql code for the UpdateCommand property either in the html page itself (like in the examples) or in the codebehind.

Comment: One thing, a friend just mentioned me that this should all be working if I check "Enable Editing" on my grid view options, but I don't have that option, only enable paging/sorting/selection... why is that?

Comment: I think your friend means this : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/czzytf25(v=vs.80).aspx . However, that option enables a default interface for editing (i.e. buttons, textboxes,...) but the actual code to update the data in sql must still be assigned to the updatecommand property. The link mentions explicitly that as long you don't do that, there won't be an "Enable Editing" checkbox on your gridview.

Comment: I've managed to fix all my commands thanks to your help, except for the delete one. This is what I did: DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [portfolioprint1] WHERE [id] = @id" , i'm getting the following error: Must declare the scalar variable "@id". (id is my primary key and its auto incremented), everything else works fine!

Comment: Did you add 'Id' to the datakeynames field of the gridview ? If not, the delete cannot work.

Comment: I believe I just did, the arrow is indeed green! Thanks again.